# Firebase Realtime Database Code doesn't wait for database read to complete

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, discord-jda

I'm currently working with Firebase Realtime Database. I'm trying to read the data once when a certain method in my program gets called.

This is a project for a Discord bot. (https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA)

The data *is* being read, however the execution order is wrong. I make the call to get the data but the program continues even-though the methods haven't been called yet properly.

To showcase my error I will include the code. Within the code I do printlines to illustrate what happens (or the order everything gets executed in).

I have attempted to work with Threads to fix this but I haven't managed to get it to work.

The code:

```
public class userLogs extends ListenerAdapter {

private FirebaseDatabase db;
private JDA jda;
private Stack<offense> allOffenses = new Stack<>();
public userLogs(FirebaseDatabase db, JDA jda){
    this.db = db;
    this.jda = jda;
}

@Override
public  void onSlashCommand(SlashCommandEvent event)
{

    if (!event.getName().equals("logs")) return; // make sure we handle the right command

    this.allOffenses = new Stack<>();
    // Selected user you want the logs from
    String userID = event.getOption("user").getAsUser().getId();


    new Thread(() -> {
        /** GET ALL MUTES*/
        db.getReference("Mutes").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        System.out.println("I am now getting all logs from the database.");

                        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            String offenderID = ds.child("offenderID").getValue(String.class);

                            if(offenderID.equals(userID)) {
                                // Get moderator
                                String modID = ds.child("moderatorID").getValue(String.class);
                                User moderator = jda.getUserById(modID);

                                // Get reason
                                String reason = ds.child("reason").getValue(String.class);

                                Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(ds.child("duration").getValue(Long.class));

                                saveOffense(new offense("Mute", moderator.getAsTag(), reason, duration));
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }).start();

    System.out.println("I just got out of the Thread. The stack size is: " + allOffenses.size());

    // Create embed
    EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder();
    eb.setTitle("Logs for user: " + jda.getUserById(userID).getAsTag());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < allOffenses.size(); i++){

        sb.append("Type: \n").append(allOffenses.get(i).getOffenseName());
        sb.append("Moderator: \n" + allOffenses.get(i).getModerator());
        sb.append("Reason: \n" + allOffenses.get(i).getReason());

        Duration dur = allOffenses.get(i).getDuration();
        if(dur != Duration.ZERO){
            sb.append("Duration: \n" + dur);
        }

    }

    eb.setDescription(sb.toString());

    event.getChannel().sendMessageEmbeds(eb.build()).queue();

}

void saveOffense(offense off){
    System.out.println("I just got in the method where I put a found offense into the stack.");
    this.allOffenses.push(off);
}
```

}

This outputs the following whenever the method gets called: (There are 3 offenses logged so that is correct)

[image]

As you can see it exists the thread before it executes the code within it. I'm very confused about this and have spent the past 5+ hours trying to fix this.

I hope that I've explained the issue correctly. Thank you all very much for your help!

Comment: Is that an Android project? If yes, have you tried to use an async approach as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)?

Comment: This is not an Android project, it's a Discord bot @AlexMamo

Comment: You need to put all your code inside the thread if you want it to execute in sequence.

Comment: This is the expected behavior: data is loaded from Firebase (and most modern cloud APIs) asynchronously (on a different thread already, you don't need to spawn a `Thread` for that in your code), and your main code continues while the data is being loaded. Then when the data is available, your `onDataChange` gets called with it and you can use it. This means that: **any code that needs the data from Firebase has to be inside `onDataChange`**, be called from there, or otherwise synchronized. See the answers I linked for the options.